# DateTime comparison and daylight saving / other oddities

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, dst

I have a very simple need with datetimes, I need to be able to compare the modification time of 2 files and I don't need any other information except which one was last updated / are they the same.

I'm wondering how datetime COMPARISON (I don't care about anything else) reacts after daylight saving.

Let's imagine you change a file at time `X`, then again at time `Y` 30 min later (but clock actually shows 30 min EARLIER because date changed due to savings).

If `X` & `Y` are 2 datetimes, what happens? Is `X > Y` or `Y > X`? Does it compare the time as it's shown or the number of ticks? (Should I do `X > Y` or should I compare `X.Ticks` vs `Y.Ticks` ?)

**Edit:** If anyone is curious the use case is I'm indexing files continuously (over years) and some of them may change rarely, I skip anything that isn't newer than when I indexed it so if I miss one, it could be a long time before it changes again and gets updated in the index.

Comment: How *exactly* are you fetching the `DateTime` values? It makes a huge difference. If you've got `DateTime` values with a `Kind` of `Utc`, you're fine... otherwise, you've got issues :(

Comment: Go see Jon's site here http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm concerned with DateTime.Now and the properties from FileInfo.LastWrite/Modifed/other, not sure on their kinds, not doing any modification on said dates myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .Net, when you pull the  the last modified date/time from a file, you can use either the [`FileInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx), which has properties such as `LastWriteTime` and `LastWriteTimeUtc`, or you can use the [`File` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has methods like `GetLastWriteTime()` and `GetLastWriteTimeUtc()`.

Use the UTC form of these, and you will not need to concern yourself with daylight saving time changes at all.

With regards to your question of comparison, you can simply compare `X > Y`.  The `DateTime` struct overrides the `Equals` method to compare based on ticks.  You can see this in the [.NET Framework Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#592).  But ticks of the `DateTime` object are not necessarily based on UTC.  The `Kind` property also comes into play.  If your working with `DateTimeKind.Utc`, then you can compare without regard to time zone or daylight saving time differences.

Do keep in mind that when the operating system retrieves the last modified time from the file system, it is impacted by the behavior *of the file system*.  While NTFS records all times in UTC, other file systems such as FAT and FAT32 record file times in *local time*.  This impacts your ability to consistently retrieve the file's modified date.

So if you are talking about file times on an NTFS volume, then you're fine.  But if you're talking about file times on a FAT32 volume (perhaps from a USB thumbdrive or a camera's SD card) then you are not guaranteed accurate conversion.  This is a good reason to format your SD cards using exFAT instead of FAT32, since exFAT includes a time zone offset, which allows for accurate conversion back to UTC.

Comment: Also, if you are comparing to the current time, be sure to use `DateTime.UtcNow` as your point of comparison.  See also: [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Comment: I'm only comparing files together however i'm comparing a date i get now to a date i stored in DB (i store them in ticks), anything special i should do when reconstructing the date from ticks to compare?

Comment: Did you store ticks based on UTC? Or something like `DateTime.Now.Ticks`?  Also, most DBs have datetime datatypes, so storing ticks isn't usually required.

Comment: I'm going to use the datetime from the properties you suggested  (LastWriteTimeUtc). However i'm not sure what EF does if i pass it a datetime. I'm storing it in a lucene index (so not a real data DB) and i'd really rather just treat it as a raw number, just wondering if i do what you suggested (var mydateticks = CurrentFile.LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks) how do i go from mydateticks back to a the original datetime object? (how do i let datetime know that it needs to reconstruct a utc datetime?)

Comment: The `DateTime` constructor [has an overload that takes ticks and a kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0d47c9c.aspx). For example, `new DateTime(yourTicks, DateTimeKind.Utc)`